# Alternative solution deprecated onchange method in Odoo16

Tags: filter, deprecation-warning, odoo-16

As the below code achieves the dynamic domain condition, this is what i want to achieve but this will get the Deprecation Warning in odoo v16, so if anybody knows the solutions that achieves similar functionality. Please comment it.

```py
@api.onchange('customer', 'picking_type_code') 
def _onchange_customer(self):
    ​if self.picking_type_code == 'outgoing' and self.customer:
        return {'domain': {
            'move_ids.product_id': [
                ('picking_id.picking_type_code', '=', 'incoming'), 
                ('picking_id.customer', '=', self.customer)
            ]}
        }
    else: 
        ​return {'domain': {'move_ids.product_id': []}}
```

Actually i know this method is deprecated that's why i'm posting here to get the alternative methods that achieves similar solution

I have already tried web_domain_field but its not working since i need the dynamic domain inside the one2many field based on parent model fields value. I'm not able to achieve it through the compute field.

Mainly I'm not able to add the domain direct directly into the field since in the inventory module we use same Object relation in different Operation Types i.e., Incoming, outgoing,..

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it it's like it's described here in this comment of the PR that introduce the warning you are seeing:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/41918#issuecomment-824946980

But even if you see the warning the feature to return domains for onchange it's still there working.

The other thing that I have done to solve this it's to provide my own modified version of the onchange for some specific abstract models as mixin that needs some virtual fields based on the idea behind the new properties fields and make it work in Odoo 12.0 because I needed to load completely dynamic data according to dynamic rules and need to setup dynamic domains from this dynamic rules on the final loaded data records... pretty crazy thing that need crazy features

Comment: def onchange_customer(self):
        if self.customer:
            domain = [('picking_id.customer' , '=' , self.customer.id) ,
                ('product_id' , '!=' , False), ('lot_number' , '!=' , False) ]
            move_records = self.env['stock.move'].search(domain)
            lot_numbers = move_records.mapped('lot_number')
            product_ids = move_records.mapped('product_id')
            return {
               'domain': {
                    'product_id': [('id' , 'in' , product_ids.ids)],'lot_number': [('id' , 'in' , lot_numbers.ids)]
                } }return {}

Comment: This  method is working actually right but whatshappening that variable that i have assigning from the mapping is returning correctly. But domain is not fetching the value, so i thought since this method has been deprecated , it will not work.
Please suggest me other than  compute field...I need solution with onchange method itself.

Comment: Did you already tried to put an static domain in the view using a compute m2m field like `[('id', 'in', compute_ids)]` and return the changed value for the field `compute_ids` on the onchange method instead of building the "new" domain with the new ids?. That's the way to go

Comment: Ya , I 've tried it but its not working..@aekis.dev

Comment: that´s the way to go, perhaps you aren't doing it right. I could help you in your scenario if you are willing to pay for a solution. See my email in the profile and write me directly with more details

Comment: I solved it using the compute method , I have been trying it using compute method but it was not working, I troubleshooted the issue. Thanks for your help.