# Unable configure the issue

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

Requirement:
Based on the customer in the stock.picking and the `picking_type_code(operation type)` is outgoing. Then in `move_ids` (one2many field of `stock.picking`) the `product_id` and the `lot_number` field many2one dropdown should dynamically filter based on the customer's incoming stock.picking record.

example:

```
@api.onchange('partner_id')
    def onchange_partner_id(self):
        if self.partner_id and self.picking_type_code =="outgoing":
            print(f"Selected partner_id: {self.partner_id.name}")

            # Filter product_ids based on the selected partner_id and picking type
            domain = [
                ('picking_id.partner_id' , '=' , self.partner_id.id) ,
                ('product_id' , '!=' , False),
                ('lot_number' , '!=' , False)
            ]

            # Fetch the actual lot numbers using the domain
            move_records = self.env['stock.move'].search(domain)
            move_records = move_records.filtered(lambda move: move.picking_id.picking_type_code == 'incoming')
            lot_numbers = move_records.mapped('lot_number')

            print(f"Updated Lot Numbers: {lot_numbers}")

            # Extract product_ids from move_records
            product_ids = move_records.mapped('product_id')

            print(f"Updated Product IDs: {product_ids}")

            # Return the domain for product_id filtering
            return {
                'domain': {
                    'product_id': [('id' , 'in' , product_ids.ids)],
                    'lot_number': [('id' , 'in' , lot_numbers.ids)]
                }
            }
```

log:

```
Selected partner_id: Floyd Steward
Updated Lot Numbers: stock.lot(34, 35, 36, 83)
Updated Product IDs: product.product(20, 21, 19, 37)
```

I know this method is deprecated but it should work right?
As you can see variable values are correctly fetching but domain is not fetching. Does anyone know what's the cause of this?

Actually I've tried using `compute_field` but same that also don't fetching the value in domain so I'm unable to troubleshoot the issue, I've been encountering

i have tried web `domain_field` and pedrabeaza​ github solution (compute_field) If you have an any different solutions also please comment

Comment: I have answered and commented the other question you have created for this. This seems to be a duplicated question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative solution deprecated onchange method in Odoo16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77527442/alternative-solution-deprecated-onchange-method-in-odoo16)

Answer (score 0):

I solved that using the compute method , Actually I have tried copute method before also but i was getting some issues, I troubleshoot it. Just with same logic just change method to compute and use @api.depends. Asssigned the values which i'm returning here using domain to a many2many field and then added that fields inside the domain attribute for product_id and lot_number field definition. This will work..